# Search console is not showing newly added (via API call) site. google-apis-explorer

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-search-console

I have created my google service account and using it to make API calls. I am submitting site via API call at search console, call successfully completed with status 204 but site is not coming up in google search console UI. 
Request URL is here 
https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/siteUrl

Comment: I m having the same issue. It has been more than 2 days that I am struggling. I am curious to know how did you fixed it.