# Unable to add service account to a site added in google search console via an API

Tags: google-api, google-search-console

## TLDR version

Is there an API to do this - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7687615?hl=en, I want to be able to map service account to user using some API, (I am able to do it manually, but the list is long)

[image]

## Long version

From what I understand there are 2 types of users

- Type 1 - Normal user (human) logging in and using google search console
- Type 2 - Google service accounts, used by application to pull data

Now I want to add several hundreds of site in Google Search Console, I found C# clients/API to do that.

I am able to add/list sites using normal user account using API, and then verify by using UI to see them getting added.

I am able (no error returned) to add/list sites using service accounts using API, but then unable to

- see service account user being added in the user list of the site. But I still see the site when I call the list api
- when pulling data for this site, I get errors

```
  Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
User does not have sufficient permission for site 'https://www.example.com/th-th/city/'. See also: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2451999. [403]
Errors [Message[User does not have sufficient permission for site 'https://www.example.com/th-th/city/'. See also: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2451999.] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]
```

It points me to this link - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7687615?visit_id=1621866886080-4412438468466383489&rd=2 where I can use the UI and manually add my service account and then everything works fine.

But I want to do the same thing via API, because I will be having hundreds of sites to add to.

Please advice on how to go about this one?

Seems like this user also had similar problem, but no solution - [How to connect Google service account with Google Search Console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64749134/1182982)

## CODE

This is the code I use to create site using normal user and client id/secret, here if I create a site I am able to see it on UI but the API (https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/sites/add) does not have option to use service account.

```
public class WebmastersServiceWrapper
    {
        private string user = "realemail@example.com";
        private readonly ClientSecrets _clientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = "example.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            ClientSecret = "example"
        };

        private readonly string[] _scopes = {
            WebmastersService.Scope.WebmastersReadonly,
            WebmastersService.Scope.Webmasters
        };

        public async Task<WebmastersService> GetWebmastersService()
        {
            var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(_clientSecrets, _scopes, user, CancellationToken.None);
            var service = new WebmastersService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "WebMasters API Sample",
            });
            return service;
        }
    }

 public class WebMasterSiteService
    {
        private readonly WebmastersServiceWrapper _connection;

        public WebMasterSiteService()
        {
            _connection = new WebmastersServiceWrapper();
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetSites()
        {
             var service = await _connection.GetWebmastersService();
             var sitesResponse = await service.Sites.List().ExecuteAsync();
             return SiteMapper.MapSites(sitesResponse);
        }

        public async Task DeleteSite(string site)
        {
            var service = await _connection.GetWebmastersService();
            var response = await service.Sites.Delete(site).ExecuteAsync();
            return;
        }

        public async Task AddSite(string site)
        {
            var service = await _connection.GetWebmastersService();
            var response = await service.Sites.Add(site).ExecuteAsync();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Here is the piece of code where I create sites using service worker, it gets created somewhere (as when I call list I get it back) but when I query that site using other APIs it fails with this error

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
    User does not have sufficient permission for site 'https://www.example.com/th-th/city/'. See also: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2451999. [403]
    Errors [
        Message[User does not have sufficient permission for site 'https://www.example.com/th-th/city/'. See also: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2451999.] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]
]
```

```
public class SearchConsoleServiceWrapper
    {
        private readonly string[] _scopes = {
            SearchConsoleService.Scope.WebmastersReadonly,
            SearchConsoleService.Scope.Webmasters
        };
        
        public SearchConsoleService GetWebmastersService()
        {
            using var stream = new FileStream("key-downloaded-from-console-cloud-google.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            var credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                .CreateScoped(_scopes)
                .UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;
            return new SearchConsoleService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential
            });
        }
    }


public class SiteService
    {
        private readonly SearchConsoleServiceWrapper _connection;

        public SiteService()
        {
            _connection = new SearchConsoleServiceWrapper();
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetSites()
        {
            var service = _connection.GetWebmastersService();
            var sitesResponse = await service.Sites.List().ExecuteAsync();
            return SiteMapper.MapSites(sitesResponse);
        }

        public async Task DeleteSite(string site)
        {
            var service = _connection.GetWebmastersService();
            var response = await service.Sites.Delete(site).ExecuteAsync();
            return;
        }
        
        public async Task AddSite(string site)
        {
            var service = _connection.GetWebmastersService();
            var response = await service.Sites.Add(site).ExecuteAsync();
            return;
        }
    }
```

## Final thoughts

Maybe I am missing something simple, also I haven't found a way to establish a relationship between my google search console account and my service account. But when I use my service account and add it as a user manually on a site, everything works and I am able to query properly.

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Hi @DaImTo I just updated my question with the code I am using, the first one I am able to create site and then use UI to see them actually present in google search console. The second one I see it being created for service account but not able to see user added to the site when using search console UI nor the query API works with it. Please advice.

Comment: Did you grant the service account access to a webmaster tools account?  Im not all that sure you can add accounts with a service account that would require that a service account has its own google search console account and im not all that sure it does.   You can use a service account to access and montor accounts it has been granted access to

Comment: Hi @DaImTo I did give permission manually and it works then, but I want to give permission not manually but using API. But I could not find an API for that.

I see people asking similar questions here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58718132/search-console-is-not-showing-newly-added-via-api-call-site-google-apis-explo and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64749134/how-to-connect-google-service-account-with-google-search-console

Comment: As far as i know there is no endpoint to add a user to your google search console account it has to be done manually.   Which is normally the case with granting a service account permissions,  as this is something that is normally done by the developer who owns the service account in the first place.

Comment: Ok @DaImTo understood. Thank you for your responses.